# R - trouble loading "forecast" package

Tags: r

When trying to load the "forecast" package in R using

```
library(forecast)
```

I get the pop-up error message: "The procedure entry point IdnToAscii could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll".

This is then followed by an error message in the console: "unable to load shared object 'C:/Documents and Settings/hq/My Documents/R/win-library/3.3/curl/libs/i386/curl.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found."

From the research I've done on this, it looks as though this problem is occurring because R is having difficulty with that specific library location.  So I've re-installed "forecast", using a different location:

```
library(forecast,lib.loc="C:/Documents and Settings/hq/Desktop/RDirectory/New Library")
```

I have checked, and the files are now in that second location.  However, when I do:

```
library(forecast,lib.loc="C:/Documents and Settings/hq/Desktop/RDirectory/New Library")
```

I get the same pop-up error message, followed by the same error message in the console: "Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Documents and Settings/hq/My Documents/R/win-library/3.3/curl/libs/i386/curl.dll':".  This suggests that R is ignoring my instruction to look in a different library location, and going back to the same location.

Apologies - I'm sure this is a very basic question, but I've never used R before.

Update - I wanted to check that this wasn't a generic problem with downloading packages from R, so I have installed another package (e1071) at random and run a random function from that package (the "naiveBayes" function), and this installed, loaded and ran perfectly.  This suggests that this is perhaps something to do with the installation of this specific package.

Update 2 - just changed the library location. Made absolutely no difference. I am using Windows XP and R version 3.3.0, if either of these is relevant...

Comment: Not sure Windows XP is still supported. Have you tried rebooting, reinstalling? Can you install packages from source using rtools?